# How to emit a Type in .NET Core

Tags: c#, system.reflection, reflection.emit

In C#, how do I emit a new Type at runtime with .NET Core? All of the examples I can find for .NET 6 don't seem to work in .NET core (they all begin with getting the current AppDomain, which doesn't exist in .NET core any more).

If possible I would appreciate an example that involves creating a Type and adding a property to the Type.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here is SO post about creating a dynamic type in .NET 4.

[How to dynamically create a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-create-dynamically-a-class-in-c)

And in the accepted answer is just one use of `AppDomain`.

```
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

Here is another SO post about a replacement of `DefineDynamicAssembly` function in .NET core.

[Is there any replace of AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937276/is-there-any-replace-of-assemblybuilder-definedynamicassembly-in-net-core)

Here it is:

```
AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

In `"System.Reflection.Emit": "4.0.1"` nuget.

Also, there is a difference in `TypeBuilder`. `CreateType` function no longer exist, instead for creating types we should use `CreateTypeInfo`. And yes, it is again from SO post.

[CreateType missing from TypeBuilder. How to port this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488458/createtype-missing-from-typebuilder-how-to-port-this)

Here is working modified example (for .NET core) of creating a Type and adding properties to the Type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class FieldDescriptor
    {
        public FieldDescriptor(string fieldName, Type fieldType)
        {
            FieldName = fieldName;
            FieldType = fieldType;
        }
        public string FieldName { get; }
        public Type FieldType { get;  }
    }

    public static class MyTypeBuilder
    {
        public static object CreateNewObject()
        {
            var myTypeInfo = CompileResultTypeInfo();
            var myType = myTypeInfo.AsType();
            var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

            return myObject;
        }

        public static TypeInfo CompileResultTypeInfo()
        {
            TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
            ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

            var yourListOfFields = new List<FieldDescriptor>()
            {
                new FieldDescriptor("YourProp1",typeof(string)),
                new FieldDescriptor("YourProp2", typeof(int))
            };
            foreach (var field in yourListOfFields)
                CreateProperty(tb, field.FieldName, field.FieldType);

            TypeInfo objectTypeInfo = tb.CreateTypeInfo();
            return objectTypeInfo;
        }

        private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
        {
            var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                    TypeAttributes.Public |
                    TypeAttributes.Class |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                    TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                    TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                    null);
            return tb;
        }

        private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
                tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                  MethodAttributes.Public |
                  MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                  MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                  null, new[] { propertyType });

            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `The type or namespace name 'FieldDescriptor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`.  I am using .net core 3.1.  Any ideas?

Comment: @salli did you copy the `FieldDescriptor` class, it is custom-defined class in the sample.

Comment: Thanks @AramKocharyan.  I figured that out after not finding the class on Microsoft site.

Comment: Why the NOP in the IL code for the set methods? Also why have labels at all?