# Add entity types after model creation in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2 and I'm trying to add an entity dynamically to the the model.
The scenario is:

1. The user creates an entity with custom properties in a web app
2. I create at runtime a class that maps this entity (see [How to emit a Type in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784393/how-to-emit-a-type-in-net-core))
3. I add the created class to the model in the `OnModelCreating` method of the db context (see https://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/)

Everything works, except when I want to write to the db a new instance of the newly created class in the same request (API call) where I created the new entity.

This is because the `DbContext` is scoped to the request (not transient), so the `DbContext` called the `OnModelCreating` method before I had the chance to create the new entity.

This is the error that I get:

```
The entity type 'People' was not found. 
Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that? I don't think it's possible to call `OnModelCreating` on demand and I can't find a way to access the `ModelBuilder` of the context to call it's `Entity` method.

Comment: So to clarify, when you do something like DbContext.NewEntityClass.Add(UserCreatedEntity) it fails because the context has no existing definition of the NewEntityClass? So you're trying to dynamically create new entity classes within your DbContext through user input?

Comment: That's correct. I updated the question with the error that I get when I do DbContext.NewEntityClass.Add(UserCreatedEntity).

Comment: the modelbuilder is not accessible from outside, and it wouldn't do anything on a context instance anyways. your model has to be defined once you create the context type you want to use to access this model, there's no way around that.

Comment: What about requesting a new `DbContext` instance after the entity has been added? Is there a way to do that for a scoped service? I add the context this way: `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>()`, which is equivalent to a `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need a new DbContext subtype, as OnModelCreating only runs once per DbContext type per AppDomain.