# Using types created at runtime in C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, runtime, reflection.emit

**Technological requirements:**

MS SQL DB, .NET Core 3.1, EF Core, C#

**That what should be done:**

I need to create some metadata-driven solution in C# that has to be able to connect to a DB and then to retrieve the data from *any* table defined in a JSON file, which program gets as an input. In the JSON file **schema, table** and **columns** are listed. For example:

```
{
   schema: 'dbo',
   table: 'customers',
   columns: [
              {
                name: 'FirstName',
                type: 'string'
              },
              {
                name: 'Age',
                type: 'integer'
              }
            ]
}
```

Solution should be able to create **class (Type)** reflecting the needs of those of the current JSON file. After that, it should use this new type to set up a `DbSet<new_type> CustomTypeList { get; set; }` in `DBContext` and subsequently configure it with `IEntityTypeConfiguration`.

**What I have done so far:**

I used the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784393/how-to-emit-a-type-in-net-core/41785168) and thus implemented some type of `RuntimeCustomTypeCreation` class that returns a new `type` created right after the beginning of my program by using `System.Reflection` and `System.Reflection.Emit` namespaces. The new type reflects exactly the structure the JSON ordered us. A new instance of that type now can be created easily with `System.Activator.CreateInstance(...)` function.

**Problem I can't get solved:**

How can I use my newly created runtime-type in my application as for example any class written as code before compilation and execution? I need to be able to do something like already written above and that is:

`DbSet<new_type> CustomTypeList { get; set; }`

Do I have to "register" my newly created type somewhere? Is this even possible? Thank you!

Comment: Casting or using generics like your `DbSet<new_type>` is a compile time operation. Creating types at runtime is, well, a runtime operation. There is no way to tell the compiler about these types that do not exist at compile time. There are at least two directions you can take, use oop and compile time known base-classes/interfaces. Or use reflection all the way down for every call or member access.

Comment: Why is it not possible to define your DbSet for your database at compile time? If you want to dynamically query a database then maybe EF core isn't the best solution?