# Cannot create dynamic type in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, .net-5, reflection.emit

I want to add `Child` as a dynamic type to a dynamic assembly:

```cs
public abstract class Parent { }       // I want to define this statically

public class Child : Parent {          // I want to define this dynamically
  private Child() : base() { }
}
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785168/9971404) example.

I added the nuget package [System.Reflection.Emit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Emit) (v 4.7.0).

Then wrote this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public abstract class Base { }

public class Program {

  public static void Main() {

    // define dynamic assembly
    var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    // define dynamic type
    var typeName = "Child";
    var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
      typeName,
      TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
      typeof(Base));
    typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
    //typeBuilder.CreateType();   // this was missing - see accepted answer below

    // test it
    try {
      typeBuilder.Assembly.GetTypes();                 // <--- throws
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException exception) {
      Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
  }

}
```

It throws this:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Could not load type 'Child' from assembly '28266a72-fc60-44ac-8e3c-3ba7461c6be4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

This failed for me in a unit testing project. It also failed on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IvuEKK).

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call [`CreateType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype?view=net-5.0). As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=net-5.0#examples) says:

> Before a type is used, the `TypeBuilder.CreateType` method must be called. `CreateType` completes the creation of the type.

You might not need to use the `Type` object that it returns for anything, but you still need to do this. Loading the type counts as "using the type" after all.

You should do:

```
typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

after you `DefineDefaultConstructor`.